# Javascript regex to auto format the number input value into a date kind of format DD - MM - YYYY

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I auto-format the input value(number) into a date kind of format (DD - MM - YYYY) upon entering each number in the input box using regex?

Example:

```
11122020 => 11 - 12 - 2020
11122    => 11 - 12 - 2
1112     => 11 - 12
111      => 11 - 1
11       => 11
1        => 1
```

What I tried so far :

```
'11122020'.replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3')
```

but unable to handle scenarios like 111, 1112 etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It's theoretically impossible given your scenarios. How would you explicitly know that '111' is 11-1 or 1-11?

Comment: This kind of date format is generally ambiguous. Not recommended to use or interpret it at all. It's guarantied to produce weird errors. Consider using some ISO8601 format instead, like "yyyy-MM-dd" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I developed a solution and for the sake of helping others put it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I developed and it's working without fail in all scenarios.

```
const formatString = (string) => {
  if (string.length === 2 || string.length === 3) {
    return string.replace(/(\d{2})/, '$1 - ');
  } else if (string.length >= 4) {
    return string.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1 - $2 - ');
  }
};

formatString('1')        // 1
formatString('12'        // 12 - 
formatString('123')      // 12-3
formatString('12345')    // 12 - 34 - 5
formatString('12345678') // 12 - 34 - 5678
```

And of course, you can convert this output into a YYYY-MM-DD format and validate whether it's a valid date or not.

Thanks.